# Update table based on LAG value and condition

Tags: sql, lag

I'm trying to update the table with a lagging value for specific field when that field is different from '1900-01-01 00:00:00'

`select Ticket_ID, Business_Area, Priority, HF_Client_Name, closed_date, Closed_Date_ID, Next_Create_date from schema.table_name order by closed_date desc;`

[image]

And this is the result I'm trying to get:
[image]

I truly appreciate any help I can get. My DB is MYSQL db.
I'm working on a solution with a LAG function, an will paste my code as soon as I have something worth showing.
Thank you all!

Rosa

Comment: Please, tag your DBMS, because updates of subquery is DBMS dependent. And post your data in (tabular) text format, [not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557). Also it would be better to provide your current attempt, because SO is not a codewriting service.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this by creating a temp table which contains all the tickets with 0. I joined my original table without the 0 tickets to this second temp table.

The most important piece was to create a temp table with maximal next created date based on that month:

```
select   a.business_area, a.priority, a.hf_client_name, DATE_FORMAT(a.closed_date ,'%Y-%m') month_of_ticket, max(next_created_date) next_created_date
        from tmp_next_lead_date a
        group by  a.business_area, a.priority, a.hf_client_name, DATE_FORMAT(a.closed_date ,'%Y-%m');
```

After that I just joined the two tables based on month of ticket and the rest of the key.

```
select a.ticket_id, a.business_area, a.priority, a.hf_client_name, a.closed_date, 
        /*DATE_FORMAT(a.closed_date ,'%Y-%m') month_of_ticket,*/  a.closed_date_id, b.next_created_date
        from tmp_missing_combination a
        join tmp_next_created_Date b 
            on  a.business_area=b.business_area 
            and a.hf_client_name=b.hf_client_name
            and **DATE_FORMAT(a.closed_date ,'%Y-%m')=b.month_of_ticket** ;
```